# Getting specific data using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL Queries. I want to get these data:

**TABLE 1:**

[image: TABLE 1]

**Table 2:**

[image: TABLE 2]

**TABLE 1 DATA**
[TABLE 1 DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T219e.png)

**TABLE 2 DATA**
[TABLE 2 DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuMyF.png)

```
 TABLE 1
  USER_FIRST_NAME
  USER_LAST_NAME

 TABLE 2
  ACTIVITY_NAME
  ACTIVITY_DATE
  ACTIVITY_TIME
```

I want to get the activities of the person/s that I am handling. or in other words

> WHERE USER_SUPERVISOR=USER_ID AND USER_FULL_NAME=COORD_NAME.

My code is below when I use this code nothing shows:

```
SELECT USER_LAST_NAME,
       USER_FIRST_NAME,
       ACTIVITY_NAME,
       ACTIVITY_DATE,
       ACTIVITY_TIME
FROM user_hierarchy
JOIN ret_activities_at_outlet
  ON user_hierarchy.USER_FULL_NAME = ret_activities_at_outlet.COORD_NAME
WHERE user_hierarchy.USER_SUPERVISOR = "1"
```

Comment: Could your provide some sample data from your tables?

Comment: @D-Shih please see my update above please help

Comment: Are you sure `user_hierarchy.USER_FULL_NAME` equal to `ret_activities_at_outlet.COORD_NAME`?
I will suggest you add a new column `USERID` in`ret_activities_at_outlet` table for link with `user_hierarchy` table

Comment: Is `ret_activities_at_outlet.ACTIVITY_TRX_ID` equal to `user_hierarchy.USER_ID`?

Comment: No, user_hierarchy.USER_ID = user_hierarchy.USER_SUPERVISOR

Comment: Please see my new query "SELECT COORD_NAME
  FROM ret_activities_at_outlet
 WHERE COORD_NAME IN (SELECT USER_FULL_NAME FROM user_hierarchy WHERE USER_SUPERVISOR="1")"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one person has many activities

```
SELECT USER_LAST_NAME,
           USER_FIRST_NAME,
           ACTIVITY_NAME,
           ACTIVITY_DATE,
           ACTIVITY_TIME
    FROM user_hierarchy
    RIGHT JOIN ret_activities_at_outlet
      ON user_hierarchy.USER_FULL_NAME = ret_activities_at_outlet.COORD_NAME
    WHERE user_hierarchy.USER_SUPERVISOR = "1"
    enter code here
```

or many person have many activities

```
SELECT USER_LAST_NAME,
       USER_FIRST_NAME,
       ACTIVITY_NAME,
       ACTIVITY_DATE,
       ACTIVITY_TIME
ret_activities_at_outlet left join user_hierarchy
  ON user_hierarchy.USER_FULL_NAME = ret_activities_at_outlet.COORD_NAME
WHERE user_hierarchy.USER_SUPERVISOR = "1"
```

Comment: Ok just gone through the image you have shown,it is incorrect to join with names.Userid should be foreign key in your ret_activities tables to maintain a relationship

Comment: Can you check my new query "SELECT COORD_NAME
  FROM ret_activities_at_outlet
 WHERE COORD_NAME IN (SELECT USER_FULL_NAME FROM user_hierarchy WHERE USER_SUPERVISOR="1")" there is still no data being displayed

Comment: SELECT COORD_NAME FROM ret_activities_at_outlet,SELECT USER_FULL_NAME FROM user_hierarchy WHERE USER_SUPERVISOR="1" ,run these quries separetly and show the data

Comment: I can get both data and it is equal but when I have subquery no data is displayed